# rbenv reporting command not found, even after installing and rehashing

Tags: ruby, rbenv, pry

I must be missing something. I know that `rbenv` works, but for whatever reason it just plain isn't.

I have `rbenv` installed with `brew` I have tried uninstalling and re-installing.

Any ideas where I should go from here?

```
~ ❯❯❯ rbenv local 2.3.0
~ ❯❯❯ pry
rbenv: pry: command not found

The `pry' command exists in these Ruby versions:
  2.2.4
  2.3.1

~ ❯❯❯ gem install pry                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       ⏎
Successfully installed pry-0.10.4
1 gem installed
~ ❯❯❯ rbenv rehash
~ ❯❯❯ pry
rbenv: pry: command not found

The `pry' command exists in these Ruby versions:
  2.2.4
  2.3.1
```

Comment: does gem take place in `~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/` location (the full path can be `~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pry`)?

Comment: @idej - it's resolving to `~/.rbenv/shims/gem`